# How to write automated test cases for user login for the application which is using AWS Cognito with MFA enabled?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I have a Web-based application that uses AWS Cognito for Identity Management. The Cognito Userpool is enabled with Multi-factor Authentication for user sign-in.

I want to write a test case to test this application for user sign-in with MFA enabled.
Any leads on how to approach this would be helpful.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.